# Extracting multiple pieces from JSON with jq, with output all on one line

Tags: json, bash, jq

my code

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Sunrise is expected at"
curl -X GET 'https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=36.7201600&lng=-4.4203400' | jq '.results.sunrise' | tr -d '"'
echo "and sunset at" 
 curl -X GET 'https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=36.7201600&lng=-4.4203400' | jq '.results.sunset' | tr -d '"'
echo "."
```

---

I want to print :

```
Sunrise is expected at 5:12:13 AM and sunset at 6:26:23 PM.
```

but I have this :

```
Sunrise is expected at
5:12:13
AM and sunset at
6:26:23 PM
```

Comment: Please post your code in order to find out where it goes wrong.

Comment: The `curl` snippet you posted works just fine for me, I get the expected output

Comment: Quotting from the api you are using : `"INVALID_REQUEST": indicates that either lat or lng parameters are missing or invalid;`. Are you sure you don't have hidden/malformed characters in your request ? (crlf, quotation marks, etc ...)

Comment: can u help me plz

Comment: thx Charles Duffy

Comment: the solution is curl -X GET 'https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=36.7201600&lng=-4.4203400' | jq '.results | "Sunrise is expected at \(.sunrise) and sunset is expected at (.sunset)."' | tr -d '"'

Answer (score 4):

There's no point to using multiple `echo`s here at all, and **definitely** no point to making two requests to the API when all the data you need is included in each result.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
curl -X GET 'https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=36.7201600&lng=-4.4203400' | \
  jq -r '.results | "Sunrise is expected at \(.sunrise) and sunset is expected at \(.sunset)"
```

If you have a more complicated approach where that's not ideal, it still helps to use more variables:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
api_output=$(curl -X GET 'https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=36.7201600&lng=-4.4203400') || exit
sunrise=$(jq -r '.results.sunrise' <<<"$api_output")
sunset=$(jq -r '.results.sunset' <<<"$api_output")
echo "Sunrise is expected at $sunrise and sunset at $sunset."
```

---

Note the use of the `-r` argument to `jq` to tell it to output "raw strings" -- this is why `tr` is not needed here. Also, because `echo` puts a newline after each argument, you should only run `echo` once per line of output desired. (The `-n` argument can suppress this on some versions, but it's not safe to rely on; better to use `printf '%s' ...` when trailing newlines are undesired).

`jq` similarly writes a newline after each line of output (as all well-behaved UNIX programs emitting text streams are intended to). Using [command substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst) removes those trailing newlines, so we don't store them inside the `sunrise` and `sunset` variables and thus reintroduce them in the `echo`.